# How to handle file-upload using Sylius' SyliusResourceBundle

Tags: symfony, file-upload, sylius, sylius-resource

I'm wondering how I can add a `file-upload` to my resource. I'm using the `SyliusResourceBundle` so all controllers are generated for me.

Routing:

```
app_product:
    resource: |
        alias: app.product
        except: ['show']
        section: admin
        grid: app_admin_product
        templates: Admin/Crud
        form: App\Form\Type\ProductType
    type: sylius.resource
```

`ProductType` is my custom form and it has a `FileType`. I can change this, but the problem is how to handle the upload. When I look into Sylius' controller I see two events being fired:

> Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController:~191

```
$event = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPreEvent(ResourceActions::CREATE, $configuration, $newResource);
```

I've tried creating a custom `EventListener` extending the `EventSubscriberInterface` and I've tried registering a service that listens specifically to `name: kernel.event_listener, event: sylius.product.pre_create` but it won't take for some reason. And even if it does!

Will it allow me to modify `$newResource` so the chosen image is saved to the database?

Comment: Post your whole service definition, you had the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sylius has the capability make any resource entity have images.
However, you can use this capability to upload any files, but it won't be able to render anything else except images without additional code to handle other formats.
Here's a PR that aimed to make this capability generic and cover any formats: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/9224
It was not merged because of multiple BC Breaks, but you can extract the code to your application.